# API Yandex Map ReferenceError тут_название_callback-функции is not defined

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/backend-docpage/#response-format__callback

согласно доке нам надо вернуть

```
callback_function({
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    ... 
  ]
})
```

но если у пользователя затупил интернет, либо наш сервак подвис, либо еще что-то случилось и ответ от сервера пришел поздно, то этой callback_function может уже и не существовать.

может быть в апи есть какие то обработчики для этого?
в голову приходит только делать

```
try {
    callback_function({
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
       ... 
     ]
   })
} catch (e) {
     if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
        // Handle error as necessary

     } else {
         throw(e);
     }
}
```

Comment: дайте, пожалуйста, полностью интерактивный пример или ссылку на страницу, где видно ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить свой обработчик [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror):

```js
window.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
    if (event.error instanceof ReferenceError) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```